# bash prompt chenged itself to a plain "#"

Tags: bash, prompt

Until I logged in today, as usual- my bash prompt was the standard "username@currpath # ".  But today, for me, it's just "# ".  If I login as root, it is normal.  bashrc seems fine (as compared to other machines".  "echo $PS1" gives me, just "#".  What happened, and how do I fix this?

I also noted that "ifconfig" has gone missing.  It works for root, yet my $PATH looks normal.

ANOTHER THING (added hours after posting):  The up and down arrows used to scroll through the command history.  Now they give output like this "^[[A^[[B" (up-then-down), yet my locale and keyboard seem to be set properly.  I am not sure if this is related to the prompt issue, but it changed at the same time.

Comment: can you elaborate on ifconfig gone missing? Maybe you logged into different session than you did previously?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing there is a problem with your user's .bashrc file.

Try copying the default .bashrc file into your home directory:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc
```

After copying the file, restart your computer.

Comment: ifconfig is working now, but the prompt is still just "#"

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be you have messed up with PS1.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x157.html

Comment: Yes, it is messed up.  But why?  How do I get it to stop messing up each boot?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have changed your user shell from /bin/bash to something else.  While logged in under your normal account, run

```
chsh
```

And select `/bin/bash` when prompted.

Comment: You've taught me something- but the correct shell is (was) selected.

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot tell you why did this happen (PS1 becoming #), you can simply set up with these special chars:

- **\a** : an ASCII bell character (07)
- **\d** : the date in "Weekday Month Date" format (e.g., "Tue May 26")
- **\D{*format*}** :   the format is passed to strftime(3) and the result is inserted into the prompt string; an empty format results in a locale-specific time representation. The braces are required.
- **\e** : an ASCII escape character (033)
- **\h** : the hostname up to the first '.'
- **\H** : the hostname
- **\j** : the number of jobs currently managed by the shell
- **\l** : the basename of the shell’s terminal device name
- **\n** : newline
- **\r** : carriage return
- **\s** : the name of the shell, the basename of $0 (the portion following the final slash)
- **\t** : the current time in 24-hour HH:MM:SS format
- **\T** : the current time in 12-hour HH:MM:SS format
- **\@** : the current time in 12-hour am/pm format
- **\A** : the current time in 24-hour HH:MM format
- **\u** : the username of the current user
- **\v** : the version of bash (e.g., 2.00)
- **\V** : the release of bash, version + patch level (e.g., 2.00.0)
- **\w** : the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
- **\W** : the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
- **\!** : the history number of this command
- **\#** : the command number of this command
- **\$** : if the effective UID is 0, a #, otherwise a $
- **\nnn** : the character corresponding to the octal number nnn
- \\ : a backslash
- **\[** : begin a sequence of non-printing characters, which could be used to embed a terminal control sequence into the prompt
- **\]** : end a sequence of non-printing characters

[Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)

Comment: It seems to be setting correctly then being overwritten.  But I can't find what is overwriting it.

Comment: does it get overwritten instantly? If so, you might want to check your processes or even try auditing software to check who edits your file.

Comment: Yes, as soon as I can login and start konsole, it's like that (for this user only).  Can you recommend some auditing software?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't tried any.

Answer (score 0):

Execution sequence for .bash_profile, .bashrc, .bash_login, .profile and .bash_logout is as follows,

```
      execute /etc/profile
      IF ~/.bash_profile exists THEN
         execute ~/.bash_profile
      ELSE
        IF ~/.bash_login exist THEN
          execute ~/.bash_login
        ELSE
          IF ~/.profile exist THEN
          execute ~/.profile
          END IF
        END IF
      END IF
```

To be on the safer side you assign `PS1` in all these files. That should certainly solve the issue.

Visit http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/execution-sequence-for-bash_profile-bashrc-bash_login-profile-and-bash_logout/ for more infomation on this

Answer (score 0):

I **typed "/bin/bash**" and- VIOLA- normalcy.  Now- where is the bash (or any) shell invoked at user login?  I edited the "passwd" file, that fixed it.  I must've modified users in a GUI that deleted the shell setting for a couple of users.

Thanks to all for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: chsh should've changed your default shell, no?

Comment: That's what I thought, but no.  Even though it showed bash as the default, and I later typed in the path when I ran it- it left the passwd file unchanged.  That could be because I was running it as a regular user (can't remember now).  I don't think I used sudo though.  Not sure if it would've mattered.  In any case, it's a good thing I looked in passwd, because another user was affected.

Comment: Did you write chsh command only? If so, you needed to specify a user too

Comment: You're right.  I didn’t specify a LOGIN (assumed it was for current user).  Should have used --help first.  Your solution would've worked fine for the user I knew about had I done it right.  Seriously, I am appalled by my ignorance!

Comment: Suppoee we have to double check with whoami :D